# Touch gloves work perfectly with iPhone but not with magic trackpad

Tags: iphone, magic-trackpad

After some experimenting I have found out that touch gloves work with Apple's magic trackpad but only if you press really hard, which is not an option.

And are there gloves that work on both?

Answer (score 1):

iphone has a capacitive sensor, the trakpad maybe an inductive one.

Comment: Frome here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductive_sensor "An inductive sensor is an electronic proximity sensor, which detects metallic objects without touching them" i dont think thats the case but you directed me in right direction! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on your gloves. See link:

[MacWorld Review](http://www.macworld.com/article/1156543/touchscreen_gloves_review.html)

This is a review from MacWorld. If you look at the Agloves entry, it states:\

> The gloves' touchscreen functionality worked great—I had no problems
>   using the gloves with my iPhone, iPad, or even my Mac’s Magic
>   Trackpad. (The Touch Screen Gloves are even thin enough that I was
>   able to type on my Mac’s keyboard without too much trouble).

Therefore, your gloves are not sensitive enough for it to pick up.